# what kind of relation/pointer in parse

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, parse-platform, relation

I am building my garage app.
-You sign in as a user

A user creates and owns different garages: i.e. `mercedes garage`, `BMW garage`, `volvo garage` etc...

in these the user can put cars: i.e.

```
BMW Garage -> (BMW X5, BMW X3, BMW530)
```

or

```
volvo garage -> (S80, v70)
```

So the user can log in, create a garage or several, and in these he can put cars.

In parse I created a `user` class, a `garage` class and `post` class.

The post class contains all pictures all users have posted.

**My question is, what is the best Parse solution?**

Do I point `Posts to User` or point `User to Posts`

And also,

when user create a garage, do I use a relation in User class? or relation in garage class?
Because the garage are personal.

------------- EDITED--------------

What I'm trying to say is how to create the classes 
I want the user to have "Garage" objects

```
(garage1, garage2...)
```

and in the garages have cars, i.e.

```
Garage1->(car1,car2) 
Garage2->(car5,car9)
```

Do I create a "`User`"-Class and then a "`Garage`"-Class

and then add a column "`Garage`":

as object?
or as a pointer? or as a relation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly what you want to do with the objects. There's nothing to stop you doing both. Having both will likely make life easier if you have many users and posts in the future. Each offers different capabilities and efficiencies depending on whether you can navigate a single pointer or wether you need a paginated list of all objects sorted in a specific way.

User would have a relationship to Garage. Garage would have a pointer to User. Both are classes. You need to set the contents of the relationship and the pointer (one isn't automatic when you set the other).